# Timer wraparound with flexible bit sizes

Tags: c, timer, bit-manipulation, integer-overflow

Given a counter/timer that increases and simply wraps at a given bit width, a well-known solution to the problem of finding the difference between two captured values of the counter (where the counter might have wrapped between the two points) is simply to perform unsigned subtraction on the counter (possibly then interpreting the result as signed if it's not known which one is larger).

For example given a 32-bit timer, code like this can be used to determine the length of time some code takes to run:

```
uint32_t start = GetSomePlatformSpecificTimer();
RunSomeOtherCode();
uint32_t end = GetSomePlatformSpecificTimer();
uint32_t platformTicksTakenByCode = end - start;
```

Or alternatively to check if some time limit has been reached:

```
uint32_t limit = GetSomePlatformSpecificTimer() + timeLimitInTicks;
while (true)
{
    bool finished = DoSomethingSmall();
    if (finished)
        break;
    if ((int32_t)(GetSomePlatformSpecificTimer() - limit) >= 0)
        return ERROR_TIMEOUT;
}
```

This works great if the timer is known to be 32 bits wide.  It also can be adjusted for 16-bit or 8-bit timers by changing the types used.

Is there a similarly simple way to do the same thing where the timer size does not match a type size?  For example, a 24-bit timer, or an 18-bit timer.

Assume that the bit size is <= 32 and is specified by a `#define COUNTER_WIDTH` in some external header (and might change).

Is the best solution to sign-extend the two counter values from `COUNTER_WIDTH` to 32-bits and then use the code above?  I can see that possibly working for the FF -> 00 rollover but I think it would break the 7F -> 80 rollover, so presumably there would have to be some sort of check for this (perhaps sign-extending if the values are near zero and zero-extending if the values are near the midpoint).  I think this also means that the difference between two values should be no more than a quarter of the counter range, otherwise it could cause issues.

Or is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of sign-extending, you could multiply up so that the full range becomes the same size as your arithmetic type.  In other words, use fixed-point arithmetic to fill the integer.  In your case, with `uint32_t`, that would look like

```
uint32_t start = GetSomePlatformSpecificTimer();
RunSomeOtherCode();
uint32_t end = GetSomePlatformSpecificTimer();
start <<= 32-COUNTER_WIDTH;
end <<= 32-COUNTER_WIDTH;
uint32_t platformTicksTakenByCode = end - start;
platformTicksTakenByCode >>= 32-COUNTER_WIDTH;
```

Obviously you'd want to encapsulate that arithmetic:

```
const uint32_t start = GetScaledTimer();
RunSomeOtherCode();
const uint32_t end = GetScaledTimer();
const uint32_t platformTicksTakenByCode = RescaleDuration(end - start);
```

with

```
uint32_t GetScaledTimer()
{
    return GetSomePlatformSpecificTimer() << 32-COUNTER_WIDTH;
}
```

```
uint32_t RescaleDuration(uint32_t d)
{
    return d >> 32-COUNTER_WIDTH;
}
```

You then have much the same behaviour as for your full-width timer, and the same option to use signed types if necessary.

Comment: This does seem like a simpler solution for this particular case.  There's another case where I'm not sure rescaling makes sense, but I need to think about it some more.